# React child component image does not load by passing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent and a child component in which parent passes an image path in order to be shown by child.
[image]

Say:

```
/* Parent */
...
...
<Child imagePath={path /*This is coming from server*/} />
...
```

I do this in the child component:

```
<img alt="..." src={require(this.props.imagePath)} />
```

This comes with a panic and says the given image, say "my_image.jpg" does not exist.

> Error: Cannot find module '/static/media/my_image.b05f9b9b.jpg'

While when I pass the image path in static string, everything goes well.

In order not to use require(....) in render method, I did as below:

```
/* ---------- Child Component --------- */
state={myImage: null};

componentDidMount(){
   let img = require(this.props.imagePath);
   this.setState({myImage : img});       
}

render(){
   return(
    <div>
        <img alt="...." src={this.state.myImage} />
    </div>
 )
}
```

Again, i get the same error.
Is there any mistakes I am overlooking?

Comment: the `img` tag `src` prop will load the image for you, you don't need to use `require`

Comment: Thanks, I want to know why does feeding the require method in static string comes up with no errors while sending the same thing with props is troublesome?

Comment: because you're trying to pass an object into the `src` prop which expects a string

Comment: but then again, the error says something else, I have no idea before actually debugging it, sorry